# If a function is continuous and positive at a point, there is a neighborhood where it is positive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

This is a practice question for my first year calculus exam. I really don't understand it. The solution is posted below so if anyone could explain it to me that would be great!

Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function at a point $c \in \mathbb R$. Suppose $f(c) > 0$. Prove there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$.

$|f(x) - |f(c) < f(c)/2$

= $|f(c) - f(x)| < f(c)/2$

=$f(c) - f(x) < f(c)/2$

= $f(x) > f(c) > 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I just expand your solution. Given that $f(c)>0$. Consider the positive real number $f(c)/2$. Then as $f$ is continuous, there is $\delta$ such that if $ c-\delta <x <c+ \delta$, we have

$$|f(x) - f(c)| < f(c)/2$$

In particular,

$$f(x) - f(c) > -f(c)/2 \Rightarrow f(x) > f(c)/2 > 0$$

whenever $c-\delta <x<c+\delta$.